# Rails 3. render on validation error

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

I have a form where a user can enter payments for an invoice. So...

```
invoice has_many   :payments
payment belongs_to :invoice
```

The problem is, when there is a validation error, let's say the user doesn't enter a required payment date, I get this error...

```
undefined method invoice_number for nil:NilClass
Extracted source (around line #10):
7: 
8: <div class="content-box-content">
9:   <div class="tab-content default-tab" style="display: block; ">     
10:   <h4>Invoice #<%= @invoice.invoice_number %> for <%= @invoice.company.name %></h4>
11:     <p>Invoice Balance $<%= sprintf("%.2f", @invoice.balance) %></p>
12:   </div>
13: </div>

payments_controller.rb
----------------------
def new
  @invoice = Invoice.find(params[:invoice_id])
  @payment = @invoice.payments.build

  respond_to do |format|
    format.html
  end
end

def create
  @payment = Payment.new(params[:payment])
  respond_to do |format|
    if @payment.save
      format.html { redirect_to payments_path, notice: 'Payment was successfully created.' }
    else
      format.html { render action: "new" }
    end
  end
end
```

So I know I have to add @invoice to the create action, somewhere in `render action: "new"`. How can I do this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Simply add `@invoice = @payment.invoice` before you do `format.html { render action: "new" }` and everything should work

```rb
def create
  @payment = Payment.new(params[:payment])
  respond_to do |format|
    if @payment.save
      format.html { redirect_to payments_path, notice: 'Payment was successfully created.' }
    else
      @invoice = @payment.invoice
      format.html { render action: "new" }
    end
  end
end
```

Calling render for a different action than the one being managed will only render the *view* of that action. It does not *call* the method of the action being rendered.

In other words: the `format.html { render action: "new" }` simply loads `new.html.erb` with the variables specified in the *create*  action, `def new` is never even touched. As a result, the `@invoice` parameter does not exist since you never defined it in your create action.